# Embedding of symmetric power of a curve in Jacobian

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a projective curve and denote by $C^{(n)}$ its $n$'th symmetric power.

My question is, when is there an embedding of $C^{(n)}$ into the Jacobian of $C$, $J$?

If $O$ is a degree $n$ point of $C$, then we may define a morphism $C^{(n)}\longrightarrow J$ by sending $P\in C^{(n)}\mapsto P - O$.

I want to try and understand when is this morphism an embedding. Clearly there is an obvious obstruction, when, for example, the genus of $C$, $g$, is (strictly) smaller than $n$. Is this the only obstruction? Is there something more?

Answer (score 1):

It is an embedding if and only if for any line bundle $L$ on $C$ of degree $n$ one has
$$
\dim H^0(C,L) \le 1.
$$

Comment: Would you care to elaborate why this is the case, for example, when $n=2$? A reference would be equally appreciated.